# I cant inject JQuery from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

First let me begin by saying that I have googled this and checked various stack overflow posts for hours. If I missed something please leave a link to that question in your answer, otherwise please post a solution that corrects my code by telling me what to add and/or remove and specify the files that I should put these edits in. If my logic is wrong please point it out and show me a solution. This is my first Chrome Extension that I am working on. I am working with one other person and we are both stumped. Thanks so much for taking the time to help.

```
File: background.js:

function clicked() {
var i = prompt("This is a test"); // this runs

    //this does not
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"jquery.3.1.1.js"}, function() {
           chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"content.js"});
        });
    });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(clicked);
```

When I launch the chrome extension by clicking the icon the input box displays but the next few lines dont work. I get the following errors:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
```

I omitted the random letter urls.

Here is manifest.json

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "not relevant",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Add description",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "jquery-3.1.1.js", "content.js" ],
"matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}],
"permissions": [
    "background",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
]
}
```

The jquery file is in the same directory as these other files.
I also have a content.js however I dont believe it has anything to do with the problem.

Also

before when I had the chrome.tabs.execute functions in background.js I tried to test the file with a .append statement the console gave me no errors but the page remained unchanged. The page is supposed to change the text content.

Comment: The error message says it all. So simply don't click your extension button when on a page with chrome:// url like settings, for example, or a page of an extension. It's not clear why you need executeScript at all since your content script is already declared in manifest. And why do you attach another onClicked listener?

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks so much! It works now!